# Angular injectormodule error

Tags: angularjs

routing is not working, it shows injector error. I have used in angular and angular link at bottom but still not working.
Index.html is showing blank page with just the error described below.
please help!!

this is my app.js

```
var app = angular.module('chirpApp', ['ngRoute ']);


app.config(function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider
    //the timeline display
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'main.html',
      controller: 'mainController'
    })
    //the login display
    .when('/login', {
      templateUrl: 'login.html',
      controller: 'authController'
    })
    //the signup display
    .when('/register', {
      templateUrl: 'register.html',
      controller: 'authController'
    });
});

app.controller('mainController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.posts = [];
    $scope.newPost = {
        created_by: '',
        text: '',
        created_at: ''
    };

    $scope.post = function () {
        $scope.newPost.created_at = Date.now();
        $scope.posts.push($scope.newPost);
        $scope.newPost = {
            created_by: '',
            text: '',
            created_at: ''
        };
    };
});

app.controller('authController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.user = {
        username: '',
        password: ''
    };
    $scope.error_message = '';

    $scope.login = function () {
        //placeholder until authentication is implemented
        $scope.error_message = 'login request for ' + $scope.user.username;
    };

    $scope.register = function () {
        //placeholder until authentication is implemented
        $scope.error_message = 'registeration request for ' + $scope.user.username;
    };
});
```

this is index.html

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Chirp</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
</head>

<body ng-app="chirpApp">
    <div id='main' class="container">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
            <div class="ng-view">
<!-- content-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="./js/chirpapp.js"></script>
</html>
```

this is the error

```
angular.js:38 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$injector/modulerr?p0=chirpApp&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Amodulerr%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.6.4%2F%24injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3DngRoute%2520%26p1%3DError%253A%2520%255B%2524injector%253Anomod%255D%2520http%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252F1.6.4%252F%2524injector%252Fnomod%253Fp0%253DngRoute%252520%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.6.4%252Fangular.min.js%253A6%253A425%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.6.4%252Fangular.min.js%253A26%253A270%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520b%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.6.4%252Fangular.min.js%253A25%253A299)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.6.4%252Fangular.min.js%253A26%253A44%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.6.4%252Fangular.min.js%253A42%253A117%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520q%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.6.4%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A495)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520g%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.6.4%252Fangular.min.js%253A41%253A476)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.6.4%252Fangular.min.js%253A42%253A149%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520q%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.6.4%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A495)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520g%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.6.4%252Fangular.min.js%253A41%253A476)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.4%2Fangular.min.js%3A6%3A425%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.4%2Fangular.min.js%3A42%3A407%0A%20%20%20%20at%20q%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.4%2Fangular.min.js%3A7%3A495)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.4%2Fangular.min.js%3A41%3A476)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.4%2Fangular.min.js%3A42%3A149%0A%20%20%20%20at%20q%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.4%2Fangular.min.js%3A7%3A495)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.4%2Fangular.min.js%3A41%3A476)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20eb%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.4%2Fangular.min.js%3A46%3A44)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20c%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.4%2Fangular.min.js%3A21%3A373)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Sc%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.4%2Fangular.min.js%3A22%3A179)
    at angular.js:38
    at angular.js:4920
    at q (angular.js:403)
    at g (angular.js:4880)
    at eb (angular.js:4802)
    at c (angular.js:1914)
    at Sc (angular.js:1935)
    at ue (angular.js:1820)
    at angular.js:33367
    at HTMLDocument.b (angular.js:3431)
```

routing is not working, it shows injector error. I have used in angular and angular link at bottom but still not working.
Index.html is showing blank page with just the error described below.
please help!!routing is not working, it shows injector error. I have used in angular and angular link at bottom but still not working.
Index.html is showing blank page with just the error described below.
please help!!

Comment: Did you read the link provided in the error output?

Comment: do you see any errors in the network tab

Answer (score 2):

Your error shows:

```
"Failed to instantiate module ngRoute  due to:"
```

if you take a closer look you have a space after ngRoute so remove that and you should be good:

```
var app = angular.module('chirpApp', ['ngRoute']);
```